# How to manage recursive return of a float?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I'm writing a C code for improving recursive functions learning. My function must calculate the average of a set of numbers received in an array. I got to calculate the sum of the numbers in the array, even to return it, same I got to calculate the average inside the function (I've printed it) but when I do the return, the main function always gets a trash number.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float sum (int array[], int n)
{
    float f; float z=n;
    if (n==0) return (array[n]);
    f=(array[n]+sum(array,n-1));;
    return f/z;
}

int main ()
{
    int *array, n, i;
    float result;

    printf("\nDimension de tu array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    array=(int *) malloc (n*sizeof (int));

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Valor en A[%d]: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    result=sum(array,n);
    printf("\n\nEl promedio es igual a: %f ", result);
}
```

Comment: Other little things that can help to improve your code. (1) Don't use `float` when you don't have because of space reasons or so. The "natural" floating point type is `double`, constants as you usually write them (`1.0`, `1E-23`) are of type `double`. (2) Don't cast the return of `malloc`, one day this might hide the fact that  you forget to include `stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return f/z;
```

Your function is supposed to compute the sum, but you are already dividing by the # of elements.

Change it to:

```
return f;
```

And divide by the # of elements in your main:

```
result = sum(array,n) / n;
```

And the other error is here:

```
if (n==0) return (array[n]);
f=(array[n]+sum(array,n-1));;
```

should be (and indented):

```
if (n==0)
    return array[n - 1];
f = array[n - 1] + sum(array,n-1);
```

The last index of an array is `n - 1`, not `n`.

Comment: +1, but there's one more mistake - `array[n]` should be `array[n-1]` in `sum`'s definition.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. Will add to answer.

Comment: +1, there is also no need to use `float` in recursive function since all values are `int`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are accessing `array[n]` for an array of size `n`. And the last index in such an array is `n-1`

Answer (score 1):

In the recursion you are assuming that `sum` returns the sum, but it actually returns the average.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the call to `sum` from `main` you call it with the number of items in the array, and then in `sum` you use that as an index into the array, which will be an unknown area beyond the array.

And then I think you should check the algorithm... If called with the number 2, 4 and 8 you will get an avarage of 2.66667, which is far from the proper avarage of 4.6667. Just do the summation in the recursive function, and divide that result with `n` in `main`.